# Visual Studio docker compose not debugging

Tags: docker, visual-studio, docker-compose

In my .net project I have a docker-compose project with a docker-compose.yml.

When I click the Docker Compose "play" Button in the top, the build process starts and the Browser opens with the swagger documentation.

When my collegue starts the same solution (from Git), everything looks fine in the console but the debugging doesnt start and the "play" Button can be pressed again.

The last lines of the his console state:

> Done!  Docker containers are ready.
> ========== Debugging ==========

Is there a setting I am missing, that prevents his solution from starting the debugger?

edit:

One thing I noticed, when my collegue looks at the lauch settings of the docker-compose project, he cannot set "Start debugging" on the Docker-Service that should be debugged.

Comment: This behavior suggests VS can't map the service to a project, is the Dockerfile in a different folder than the project?

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark: if this is an issue with service to project mapping you can manually configure the project to be used for debugging bet setting the label "com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name" to the name of the project (no file extension).

For instance, for WebApplication.csproj you can edit your docker-compose.override.yml to include:

```yaml
webapplication1:
  labels:
      com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name: "WebApplication1"
```

Comment: I dont know why, but what helped was sending my docker-compose.dcproj.user file to him.
There was an entry, he didnt have:<ActiveDebugProfile>Docker Compose</ActiveDebugProfile>
How it got there, or why he didnt have I still dont know. But for now the case is closed^^